# Locating project-specifc configuration files from imported modules

Tags: python-2.7

Project structure:

```
/lib/modules/mod1.py  
/mod2.py  
/subdir1/subdir2/mod3.py  
/configs/config.yaml
```

`mod3.py` imports `mod2.py`. `mod2.py` imports `mod1.py`. `mod1.py` loads configuration files that are at a relative path to `mod2.py` using `os.getcwd()`.

The problem is that when `mod3.py` imports `mod2.py`, `mod1.py` attempts to load the config files from a path relative to `mod3.py` (i.e. /subdir1/subdir2/configs/config.yaml instead of /configs/config.yaml)--this, of course, doesn't work.

I believe understand why this isn't working (`os.getcwd()` get the path of the originally executed file).

How can I fix this so that `mod1.py` will use a path relative to `mod2.py` even when `mod2.py` is imported from `mod3.py`?

Comment: Perhaps rewriting the code to avoid loading files from relative locations would be the best option, but if you must, take a look at `mod2.__file__`...

Comment: The problem is that the location of `mod2.py` will vary by project, but the files within the project will always follow a relative path. In the example, `mod1.py` is loaded from within the project structure--but if that were loaded from a location outside the project structure, the location of `mod2.py` would be used to establish the location of config.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find a built-in way to do this in Python, so what I ended up doing is this:

```
mod1.py:
configs_list = os.getcwd().split('/')
for x in configs_list:
    # Check each directory in list, bottom up. 'pop()' list on
    # each failure. Assign var and break loop when configs path is found.
    if not os.path.exists('/'.join(configs_list) + '/configs'):
        configs_list.pop()
    else:
        configs_path = '/'.join(configs_list) + '/configs'
        break
```

`configs_path` is then used to prefix the specific configuration file name(s) in `mod1.py`. Since every call to `mod1.py` will occur from within a project's directory structure, and every project has only one `configs` directory, this should (and has so far) correctly identified the `configs` directory regardless of where in the project the given script is being run from.

I'm open to better or more Pythonic ways of doing this, if anyone has input.